# Compiler Code Generation: Address Descriptors and Arrays

Tags: compiler-construction

I´m building a simple Compiler from the DECAF language to MIPS assembly. Right now I´m able to generate three address code and I´m starting with the code generation phase.

On the several books the structure of Register Descriptors and Address Descriptors are used. [image]

The problem I´m facing it that I don´t know how to save data on the address descriptor for an array access since my three address code usually has a temporary saving the offset of the index of the array and this temporary may change during runtime.

For example:

```
y := b[$t1], x
```

On the cases of simple variables it´s easy because I have the identifier and even an integer that corresponds to the memory locaction of the variable. How can I manage the cases of arrays to get the address descriptor working in my compiler?

Thank you